# Using a link and submit button to submit a form

Tags: php, html

I am working on a website. I would like the website to redirect from index.php to index.php?lang=En.

This is because the site is multi-lingual and the default language needs to be set to English on the home page. I used the header() method to do this but that causes a redirect loop as the site keeps reloading forever.

How can I overcome this barrier?

Comment: show us the part of the code where you set/check language and set the redirection

Comment: Your title doesn't match your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your PHP:

```
<?php
// Default to English if $_GET['lang'] isn't set
$lang = isset($_GET['lang']) ? $_GET['lang'] : 'En';

// If language not in array of available languages, reset to English
if (!in_array($lang, array('En', 'Es', 'Fr'))) {
   $lang = 'En';
}    

header('Location: index.php?lang=' . $lang);
?>
```

In your HTML:

```
<a href="index.php?lang=En">English</a>, 
<a href="index.php?lang=Es">Español</a>,
<a href="index.php?lang=Fr">Français</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do like this:

```
if(!isset($_GET['lang']) {
    header('location: http://www.example.com/index.php?lang=En');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if the `lang` parameter exists in the URL, and do the redirect only if it doesn't:

```
if (!isset($_GET['lang']) {
    header('Location: http://www.example.com/index.php?lang=En');
}
```